# Force per unit area on conducting sheet in magnetic field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

Question from I.E. Irodov (3.260)

> [image]
>
> [image]

I’m having trouble with the (c) part because the external magnetic field should be towards the right to give such a result,hence the force on unit area should be downwards,I’m also unable to find the magnitude in (c) part.Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please take a minute to read our [guidelines for homework and exercise questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714) as well as [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093). We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and we prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The case c) as depicted (assuming field lines are in the plane of the paper) implies two things:

- the current flows perpendicularly into the plane of the paper;
- the total field magnitude has left-to-right component on both sides, but field is weaker on the right-hand side.

This situation will occur if the external field has non-zero horizontal component $\mathbf B_{h}$ (left-to-right) and vertical component $\mathbf B_v$(bottom-to-top).

The horizontal component will contribute with force directed downwards (according to formula $\mathbf F = \int \mathbf j\times\mathbf B\,dV$). The vertical component will contribute with force directed to the right.

It is not clear why the solution in Irodov claims there is only force to the right. Perhaps it would be true if the plate was infinite and with zero ohmic resistance; then the sum of Lorentz forces acting on the current-forming mobile charge carriers would not translate into ponderomotive force on the plate, but would accelerate only the mobile charge carriers themselves (and change the current in the plate).

Comment: Can you please explain more on the consequences when plate is infinite with 0 resistance and also why ponderomotive force would be zero(I just know it is the force that translates a current carrying wire)but I don’t get the correlation here.Thanks

Comment: Well the magnetic forceson the microscopic level act on the mobile charge carriers that move, not on the rest of the plate. Ordinarily the mobile charge carriers will pile up a little in places where the plate resists their movement (region of high resistance or conductor boundary) and then push on the rest of the conductor with equal force - this is how Ampere forces occur in electromotor. But if the original force is in the plane, and there is nothing in that plane that would make the charges pile up (no resistance and no boundary), then the mobile charges won't push on the plate.